# Cannot set Location as String

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Hi I have no idea why I've gotten error on one of my column tables. It says that my '**Location**' cannot be put as **String**. Also I hardcode my Location and Address because I do not need users to key in any address (I've put it in a form of a spinner). So I tried to hardcode my '**Location**' and '**Address**' into my SQLite database. I have no problem storing my other Spinners into the database. So please help me out!

DBADapter:

```
public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "powerfood2014";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

public static final String KEY_RESTID = "locationId";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    private static final String LOCATION_TABLE = "location";

private static final String CREATE_LOCATION =
            "create table if not exists location (locationId integer primary key autoincrement, " + "location VARCHAR);";

private final Context context;

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_LOCATION);
        }

  @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_LOCATION);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
//---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close()
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }
 public long insertLocation(String location, String address) {

        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();

        initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, "Somerset 313 Powerfood");
        db.insert(LOCATION_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        initialValues.put(KEY_LOCATION, "Vivo City Powerfood");
        db.insert(LOCATION_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        //insert row
        long locationId = db.insert(LOCATION_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        return locationId;
    }
}
```

Here's my Location class:

```
public class Location extends Activity {
Spinner spinner1;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

public void buttonOnClickL(View v) {

        Log.d("test", "adding");
        //get data from form
        Spinner location = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        db.open();
        long id = db.insertLocation(location.getSelectedItem().toString());
        db.close();


        Toast.makeText(Location.this, "Customer successfully registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomePage.class));


    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
    error: method insertLocation in class DBAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
    required: String,String
    found: String
    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

error: method setOnItemSelectedListener in class AdapterView cannot be applied to given types;
    required: OnItemSelectedListener
    found: Location
    reason: actual argument Location cannot be converted to OnItemSelectedListener by method invocation conversion
    where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Adapter declared in class AdapterView

Answer (score 1):

As in log :

> error: method insertLocation in class DBAdapter cannot be applied to
>   given types;

because `insertLocation` method takes two String parameters instead of one and you are passing only one parameter when calling insertLocation method from Activity.

```
    String str_location=location.getSelectedItem().toString();
    long id = db.insertLocation(str_location,<PASS_SECOND_PARAM_HERE>);
```

Comment: If I were to remove my second parameter, it gives me the new error log. (logcat updated)